# PySpark: how to clear readStream cache?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am reading a directory with Spark's `readStream`. Earlier I gave the local path, but got **FileNotFoundException**. I have changed the path to hdfs path, but still the execution log shows its referring to the old settings (local path).

```
22/06/01 10:30:32 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, my.nodes.com, executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/myuser/testing_aiman/data/fix_rates.csv does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:129)
```

Infact I have hardcoded the path variable, but still its referring to the earlier set local path.

```
df = spark.readStream.csv("hdfs:///user/myname/streaming_test_dir",sep=sep,schema=df_schema,inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

i also ran `spark.sql("CLEAR CACHE").collect`, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the `spark.readStream()`, I ran the following code:

```
spark.sql("REFRESH \"file:///home/myuser/testing_aiman/data/fix_rates.csv\"").collect
spark.sql("CLEAR CACHE").collect
```

`REFRESH <file:///path/that/showed/FileNotFoundException>` actually did the trick.